# Error in inserting values in mysql in php

Tags: php, sql, forms, post

here is my code

> `if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
>
>
>     $response["success"] = 0;
>     $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";
>
>     die(json_encode($response));
> }
>
>
> $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
>
> $query_params = array(
>     ':user' => $_POST['username']
> );      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////ERROR////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> try {
>
>     $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
>     $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
> }
> catch (PDOException $ex) {
>
>     $response["success"] = 0;
>     $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
>     die(json_encode($response));
> }
>
> $row = $stmt->fetch();
> if ($row) {
>
>     $response["success"] = 0;
>     $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
>     die(json_encode($response));
> }
>
> $query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";
>
>
> $query_params = array(
>     ':user' => $_POST['username'],
>     ':pass' => $_POST['password']
> );
>
> try {
>     $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
>     $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
> }
> catch (PDOException $ex) {
>
>     $response["success"] = 0;
>     $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
>     die(json_encode($response));
> }
>
> $response["success"] = 1;
> $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
> echo json_encode($response);
>
>
>  } else { ?>  <h1>Register</h1>   <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
>   Username:<br /> 
>   <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
>   <br /><br /> 
>   Password:<br /> 
>   <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
>   <br /><br /> 
>   <input type="submit" value="Register New User" />   </form>     <?php }`
>
>   
>   ?>

I have marked the line with error. This is the error[image: Screenshot of error]. I have wamp server installed and this is the link to the tutorial i am following [mybringback](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13130/android-mysql-register-and-login-php-scripts/) and in that look at register.php v.02

here are the contents of config.php

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Front controller for config view / download and clear
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin-Setup
 */

/**
 * Core libraries.
 */
require './lib/common.inc.php';
require_once './libraries/config/Form.class.php';
require_once './libraries/config/FormDisplay.class.php';
require_once './setup/lib/ConfigGenerator.class.php';

require './libraries/config/setup.forms.php';

$form_display = new FormDisplay();
$form_display->registerForm('_config.php', $forms['_config.php']);
$form_display->save('_config.php');
$config_file_path = ConfigFile::getInstance()->getFilePath();

if (isset($_POST['eol'])) {
    $_SESSION['eol'] = ($_POST['eol'] == 'unix') ? 'unix' : 'win';
}

if (PMA_ifSetOr($_POST['submit_clear'], '')) {
    //
    // Clear current config and return to main page
    //
    ConfigFile::getInstance()->resetConfigData();
    // drop post data
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
} elseif (PMA_ifSetOr($_POST['submit_download'], '')) {
    //
    // Output generated config file
    //
    PMA_downloadHeader('config.inc.php', 'text/plain');
    echo ConfigGenerator::getConfigFile();
    exit;
} elseif (PMA_ifSetOr($_POST['submit_save'], '')) {
    //
    // Save generated config file on the server
    //
    file_put_contents($config_file_path, ConfigGenerator::getConfigFile());
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: index.php?action_done=config_saved');
    exit;
} elseif (PMA_ifSetOr($_POST['submit_load'], '')) {
    //
    // Load config file from the server
    //
    $cfg = array();
    include_once $config_file_path;
    ConfigFile::getInstance()->setConfigData($cfg);
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
} elseif (PMA_ifSetOr($_POST['submit_delete'], '')) {
    //
    // Delete config file on the server
    //
    @unlink($config_file_path);
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
} else {
    //
    // Show generated config file in a <textarea>
    //
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: index.php?page=config');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
```

You are creating a statement but you didn't create the PDO object `$db` first. Its nowhere to be seen. It has to be in this order

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
```

Example code from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) to help you explain how to create a `PDO` object

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';   //replace 'dbname' with your database name
$user = 'dbuser';    // whats your database username?
$password = 'dbpass';  // database password?

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: The OP has not edited the code properly , there is already a `config.php` on his code , So I am afraid that this code is already in there.

Comment: If it was there, that specific error message would not be there. See their attached screenshot

Comment: not working. I did add the statement you told me in the try block and i am still getting error and it says undefined variable user,password, dsn

Comment: Yes then add those variables. How do you expect to connect to a database without specifying the database connection details

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni, Post the contents of your `config.php` on the question.

Comment: can you show me how?? i am new to php, just started learning today

Comment: Yep sure, see this excellent doc : http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, Maybe he used `$db1` instead .. who knows ? That is why I asked for the `config.php`

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni, That is **really really** messed up. Go with the [**Manual**](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).. Hanky Suggested. **Voting up !**

Comment: I did read the manual and modified the code accordingly but still it is not inserting the values. here is the modified code $dsn = 'mydb';
$user = '';
$password = '';
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }

Comment: I think you are doing too fast. Read and understand the manual and see what it requires and if there are any new error messages

Comment: `dsn=mydb` is completely wrong and is not in proper format as suggested by the example

Comment: I did change it to this $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1'; sill not working.

Comment: how shall i find the database name as i haven't created one yet??

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni - If you want to do database-operations, you would have to have to create a database before you do the operations on it. You could create a database in phpMyAdmin.